# Custom Customer Edit Page: Upload PDF file and retrieve for display

Tags: php, jquery, magento

I followed this tutorial [Add Custom Edit Customer Tab](http://mydons.com/how-to-add-custom-tabs-to-magento-customer-edit-page/) to create a custom tab and page for my customer.

I would like to make it as dynamic page that fetches data from the database however I don't know how to start it.

So far this is my progress

[image]

All the codes were copied from [Add Custom Edit Customer Tab](http://mydons.com/how-to-add-custom-tabs-to-magento-customer-edit-page/).

I'm new to magento and I don't now how to start creating a dynamic page in the admin page.

<strike>My goal is to upload a PDF file for every customer and display it below.</strike>

UPDATE: My goal is to create a magento module that allow admin to upload pdf file in the backend and will dynamically display on the customer login page.

I would like to know were can I create/relate my database table/attribute so that it will get and store the exact customer ID and file.

Is there any tutorials or blogs that you can recommend?

In case I will create another similar customer page that uploads PDF    file, is there a way also that I will not repeat my self doing the    same code?

I hope you can help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to solve that problem is to understand how to create a simple module.

Allan Storm has one of the best blogging tutorial that can help you.

If you already understand the basic of Magento module you can advance in making complicated admin backend.

You can start by building **Magento Admin Grid**.

You can start on this tutorial http://navaneeth.me/creating-magento-extension-with-custom-database-table/#.VkwhrXYrKUk upon following, update the rosource model and collection model, extend them with this

**Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract** - (extend this on your resource model)

**Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract**  - (extend this on your collection model)

To create upload file, try to understand this link http://arabgento.com/en/techniques-of-uploads-files-inside-magento/

don’t forget to declare your from container with (‘enctype’ => ‘multipart/form-data’)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Tyler! This really helps.

Answer (score -2):

For upload pdf and display it :

1. If you want to display pdf than use use "iframe" tag.
2. If you want to convert `pdf` to `png` or `jpg` and display than  upload the `pdf` using `AJAX` on server and convert that pdf using "`imagemagick`" and display.